# Error running 'RegistrationActivity': The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest

[image]

---

I can't run `my registrationActivity` as it gives me the error:

> The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter

And I don't know how to solve, what should I put in my android manifest?

Also, I'm getting 
`java.lang.NullPointerException` with the if below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseAuStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null){
                Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity (intent);
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put it in your androidmanifest.xml

inside the application tag

```
<activity
        android:name=".YOURACTIVTYNAME">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Ok, that worked but I´m having a nullPointerException on my mainActivity          SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) findViewById(R.id.frame);

        flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        flingContainer.setFlingListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {

Comment: ask a question and post it, not here